# Adding this function into an existing function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-events

I am trying to add this function into a another function named function showTicks(), how could I nest this all into one. With the HTML onchange functions.

JavaScript code (EDIT):

```
function showTicks () {
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
var likeShield = document.getElementById("likeShield");
var chooseShield = document.getElementById("chooseShield");
var cb3 = document.getElementById("cb3");
var cb4 = document.getElementById("cb4");
function checkchecks() {
if (
    likeShield.value=="noShield" && chooseShield.value == "ely"
    && (cb3.checked || cb4.checked)
) {
    document.getElementById("cb2").checked=true;
}
}
likeShield.onchange=checkchecks;
chooseShield.onchange=checkchecks;
cb3.onchange=checkchecks;
cb4.onchange=checkchecks;
}
```

HTML Code for the above:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJavascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="likeShield" onchange="showTicks()">
<option value="select1">Select</option>
<option value="yesShield">Yes</option>
<option value="noShield">No</option>
</select>

<select id="chooseShield" onchange="showTicks()">
<option value="select1">Select</option>
<option value="arc">Arcane</option>
<option value="ely">Elysian</option>
<option value="spec">Spectral</option>
<option value="anylist">Choose any</option>
</select>

<table border = "1">
<tr>
  <th> tickbox </th>
  <th> shield parts </th>
  <th> description </th>
  <th> cost </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="cb1"></td>
  <td> arc sigil </td>
  <td> Large magic part </td>
  <td> 5m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb2"></td>
  <td> arc shield </td>
  <td> A extremely powerful magic shield </td>
<td> 60m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb3"></td>
  <td> arc special item </td>
  <td> special element </td>
<td> 10m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb4"></td>
  <td> elysian sigil  </td>
  <td> A sigil found by dragons </td>
  <td> 50m </td>
</tr>   
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb5"></td>
  <td> elysian shield </td>
  <td> A extremely powerful ranging shield </td>
  <td> 40m </td>
</tr>   
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb6"></td>
  <td> elysian special item </td>
  <td> A special attack attached to shield </td>
  <td> 25m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb7"></td>
  <td> spectral sigil  </td>
  <td> easily obtainable from goblins </td>
  <td> 4m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb8"></td>
  <td> spectral shield </td>
  <td> Impressive stats </td>
  <td> 15m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb9"></td>
  <td> spectral special item </td>
  <td> Does double damage </td>
  <td> 30m </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Solution, however it does not work simultaneously:

```
function showTicks()
{
if (chooseShield.value == ("ely"))
{
document.getElementById("cb1").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("cb2").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("cb3").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("cb4").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("cb5").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("cb6").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("cb7").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("cb8").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("cb9").disabled=true;   
  }
  }

function checkchecks() 
{
if(likeShield.value == ("noShield") && chooseShield.value == ("ely") && (cb3.checked == true || cb4.checked == true))
{
document.getElementById("cb2").checked=true;
}
likeShield.onchange=checkchecks
chooseShield.onchange=checkchecks
cb3.onchange=checkchecks
cb4.onchange=checkchecks       
} 
}
```

Comment: Please don't use the `onchange` attribute. Use `addEventListener` or [jQuery](http://jquery.com) instead.

Comment: so I use an addEventListener on the HTML code?

Can you please explain.

Comment: `cb3.addEventListener("change", checkchecks)` (can't you pick another function name than `checkchecks`, please? It sounds like stuttering)

Comment: Do you want to add the entire `onload` handler to `showTicks`, or only add `checkchecks` there?

Comment: You can't modify an existing function, but you can easily replace it with another one that calls the former version: `var oldST=showticks; showticks=function(){...; oldST.apply(this,arguments)};`

Comment: Hi I want the entire onload handler in showTicks.

I currenly have in my html code onchange="showTicks()" but that means I will need to add another one?

Comment: and yes you can change the checkChecks

Comment: You can have multiple `load` handlers if you attach them as `document.addEventListener("load", function(){...})`. Alternately, just use the jQuery [`$(document).ready(function(){...})`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), which also accumulates the 'ready' handlers.

Comment: Hmm i prefer this simple javascript easier to understand. Could you check the above code I edited it sill doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML code"? `document.onload = ...` is javascript code, not HTML

Comment: `function showTicks () { document.addEventListener("load", function() {` _defines_ a function that will _attach_ a `load` _listener_ to the document. Unless `showTicks` is called before the document load, the `load` listener will never run.

Comment: Remove the first line. Then the rest of the lines will execute once the document is fully loaded.

Comment: Ok I have the HTML code up. Should be easier to understand I have onchange functions on both selects showTicks(). So when i execute the code it should do the above.

Comment: I will repeat myself. You shouldd use `.addEventListener("change", checkchecks)` instead of `.onchange = "change"`.

Comment: Oh and remove all the `onchange="showTicks()` from the HTML.

Comment: But I have code in the showTicks() which will then not work

Comment: As it stands now, it reads: 1) when a select is changed 2) wait for the page load, then whenever a select is changed, 3) checkchecks.

Comment: Could you show this on JSFiddle so I can see how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Either attach `checkchecks` on document load, or don't wait for document load from `showticks`

Comment: Can I show you the jQuery way? It's _very_ readable.

Comment: Erm I would really like it in plain JavaScript since I have done mostly all in that. If that isnt any trouble

Comment: Ok haha that will do nicely.

Comment: @Jav Dvorak Hey did you manage to work it out?

Comment: I'm a slow typer but it's done now.

Comment: Please do not delete the content of your question. Even if you no longer need an answer, it may still be helpful for someone else later on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to collect all onLoad handlers to one function. Use `window.addEventListener("load", ...` to do something on page load - you can repeat this line on multiple places and all handlers will run instead of the latest one. On the same note, use `addEventListener("change", ...` instead of `onChange = ...`:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {                    // note here
    var likeShield = document.getElementById("likeShield");
    var chooseShield = document.getElementById("chooseShield");
    var cb3 = document.getElementById("cb3");
    var cb4 = document.getElementById("cb4");

    function checkchecks() {
        if (
        likeShield.value == "noShield" && chooseShield.value == "ely" && (cb3.checked || cb4.checked)) {
            document.getElementById("cb2").checked = true;
        }
    }
    likeShield.addEventListener("change", checkchecks);     //note here
    chooseShield.addEventListener("change", checkchecks);
    cb3.addEventListener("change", checkchecks);
    cb4.addEventListener("change", checkchecks);
})​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hz7KF/2/

Since your javascript is valid as soon as the page itself is loaded, you don't need to wait for other resources as well. Modern browsers reveal the `domReady` event, but you cannot rely on that as IE8 does not know this event.

jQuery (http://jquery.com/) defines the `ready` event. It uses `domReady` where possible, and uses a fallback for IE. JQuery also defines a shorter syntax for most dom-manipulation functions in Javascript:

```
$(function(){                                //or $(document).ready(function(){
    var likeShield = $("#likeShield");
    var chooseShield = $("#chooseShield");
    var cb2 = $("#cb2"); //note that you did not cache this element
    var cb3 = $("#cb3");
    var cb4 = $("#cb4");

    function checkchecks() {
        if( likeShield.val()=="noShield" && chooseShield.val()=="ely" && (cb3.is(":checked") || cb4.is(".checked")){
            cb2.prop("checked",true)
        }
    }

    likeShield.on("change", checkchecks);
    chooseShield.on("change", checkchecks);
    cb3.on("change", checkchecks);
    cb3.on("change", checkchecks);
}
```

Since performance is not the bottleneck here, you can trade off performance (tens of microseconds) for readability by not caching the elements. Attaching the handler to all `input`s and `select`s (instead of an enumerated set) also prevents potential future bugs when the logic changes:

```
$(function(){
    $("input, select").on("change",function(){ 
        if( $("#noShield").is(":selected") && $("#ely").is(":selected") 
            && ( $("#cb3").is(":checked") || $("#cb4").is(":checked") )
        ){
            $("#cb2").prop("checked",true); 
        }
    })
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hz7KF/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply much appreiciated. But it still isnt working for me ugh. However whilst you were doing that I did find a solution but it only works in the function checkChecks(). I also wrapped it around the function showTicks() but that didnt work. But they both work on their own. How can i attach them to showTicks. SHOWN ABOVE IN NEW EDIT.

Comment: @user1832421 How come it isn't working for you? It's a copy-paste of the fiddle. What are you testing in?

Comment: notepad++. Is the HTML exactly the same

Comment: @user1832421 now that you replaced your question with your answer, you have invalidated the question, invalidated my answer, wasting one hour of my effort. Not only I had no chance of knowing you were not developing for a browser, by removing your code, you have ensured nobody will understand why I have given the answer. Please don't ever remove vital information from the question. If you find your own solution, write your own answer instead of modifying the question. It's still unfair that you have not made even one mention of Notepad++ in the question. Notepad++ is not a web browser.

Comment: Sorry but I have been trying almost all day. But it only works seperately and does not add the code previously in the showTicks(). That is all I want it to do, and your part and my part will work.

Comment: I am writing the code in Notepad++ and the webpage is displayed in Firefox

Comment: Please revert your edit and write an answer instead.

Comment: Please don't say you're testing in Notepad++ when you're testing in Firefox. I'm getting angry now. I'm going to delete my answer.

Comment: Sorry Sorry Sorry! I am quite new to JavaScript so I am still learning. I thought you meant what IDE I am using. I have changed the answer at the top I want those two functions to combine when the onchange is executed. If thats all clear now.

Comment: @user1832421 please don't ever remove vital information from the question. I have reverted to a prior version. Copy out your answer from the revision history and post it as an answer, not as a part of the question.

Comment: It wont let me write my answer to my own question

Comment: Then I'll do some debugging in firefox. It's updating now but I can't see any reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: Also I'm sure the jQuery version works everywhere.

Comment: @user1832421 The fiddle is working for me in firefox - just as I thought it would.

Comment: @user1832421 perhaps missing `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the issue?

Comment: I have got the doctype declaration. Since i couldnt post my solution I have put it under my question. Just want both functions to be combined and work at the same time.

Comment: So as in the first function disables the checkboxes except 1, 2, 3 and 4. But it still needs to disable the rest when the second function runs so when checkbox 3 or 4 is ticked, checkbox 2 is automatically checked. Currently if I do it seperately only the second one works and the first function is useless.

Comment: Oh. Then you may need to combine the `change` handlers, if you want to define the order of their execution..

Comment: Ok so how I could do that. I did onchange="showTicks(); checkchecks()". in the HTML but that does not work

Comment: `You can't modify an existing function, but you can easily replace it with another one that calls the former version: var oldST=showticks; showticks=function(){...; oldST.apply(this,arguments)};` – Jan Dvorak 3 hours ago

Comment: Hmm thats confusing lol. So close to doing this. So would it be

var oldST=showTicks; showTicks=function() 
{
 if(likeShield.value == ("noShield") && chooseShield.value == ("ely") && (cb3.checked == true || cb4.checked == true))
{
document.getElementById("cb2").checked=true;
}
likeShield.onchange=checkchecks
chooseShield.onchange=checkchecks
cb3.onchange=checkchecks
cb4.onchange=checkchecks

Comment: I can't see you call `oldST` in the replacement function. `oldST.apply(this,arguments)` is a way to ensure the original function gets its arguments.

Comment: I cant really answer my own question which is kind of annoying. Could you show it on another answer that would be of great help.